# Mi preloader me sale atrás

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Tengo un pequeño preload de cargar 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la funcion que se cumple esañadir dicho preload al seleccionar el menu de opciones en la barra lateral, cuando se preciona un link 
se aplica un clase .html-over

`.html-over{opacity: 0.8;background: black;}` y el preload.

ahora mi preload sale atras lo cual me opaca su color con el opacity

codigo del preload

```
#startup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Pone en tu preloader z-índex:999;

Answer (score 0):

Ponele **position relative** al div padre y al div del loader Z-index: 9999.

Si querés que sea responsivo no te recomiendo usar porcentajes en top y left. Sino top: 0 left: 0 y la dimensión se la da el div padre.